# How to get the Physical data from create direct data base query in OBIEE?

Tags: api, soap, oracle11g, oracle10g, soapui

We tried to create a report using  Create Direct Database Query

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v6="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v6:executeSQLQuery>
            <v6:sql>EXECUTE PHYSICAL  CONNECTION POOL "Snowflake"."SDB" select \* from REGION WHERE(1=2)</v6:sql>
            <v6:outputFormat></v6:outputFormat>
            <v6:executionOptions>
                <v6:async>?</v6:async>
                <v6:maxRowsPerPage>200</v6:maxRowsPerPage>
                <v6:refresh>?</v6:refresh>
                <v6:presentationInfo>TRUE</v6:presentationInfo>
                <v6:type>?</v6:type>
            </v6:executionOptions>
            <v6:sessionID>oqfrnmhpgdfepcgcaqca0m5v3i65gp0re9r2a3feb4777lae</v6:sessionID>
        </v6:executeSQLQuery>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this soap request, we cannot get a response. how to resolve this?

How to get the data in a physical layer ?

Is there any api's to get the physical layer data ?

This query is created by oracle "EXECUTE PHYSICAL  CONNECTION POOL "Snowflake"."SDB" select * from REGION"

This is a Direct databse query.

Comment: Why is this tagged with the Smartbear tool [tag:sopaui]?